# merge facebook profile with text and image

Tags: php, facebook, image

I'm trying to biuld an eapplication for Facebook where I merge the users profile image with a background image and the name of the user. This image is a reward for those who succesfully answer a quiz.

This is the relavant code from the page where the user is direceted after submitting there answers:

```
        if ( $totalCorrect == 10) {
        echo "Congrats!";

            echo "<div id='results'>$totalCorrect / 10 correct</div>";


        echo '<img src="image.php">';

        ?>
```

And this is the code in image.php

```
<?php
// Create image instances




$im = imagecreatefromjpeg('xxx.jpg');



$black = ImageColorAllocate($im, 0, 0, 0); 




//The canvas's (0,0) position is the upper left corner 
//So this is how far down and to the right the text should start 
$start_x = 200; 
$start_y = 20; 

$font = 'arial.ttf';


Imagettftext($im, 12, 0, $start_x, $start_y, $black, $font, 'text to write'); 

$url = "http://graph.facebook.com/".$user_profile. "/picture";


$dest = imagecreatefromjpeg($url);

// Copy and merge
imagecopymerge($im, $dest, 10, 10, 0, 0, 180, 180, 100);


//Creates the jpeg image and sends it to the browser 
//100 is the jpeg quality percentage 

// Output and free from memory
header('Content-Type: image/jpg');
imagejpeg($im);



imagedestroy($dest);
imagedestroy($src);
?>
```

If I exchange the $url to a static image the code works, but not whene i try to fetch the profile of the user. Any suggestions? Thank's in adwance!

Answer (score 2):

create new php file name a.php and store following

```
$headers = get_headers('https://graph.facebook.com/".$user[id]."/picture',1); 
$url = $headers['Location'];
```

on the original file, call the a.php file like below:

```
require_once 'a.php';

$dst = imagecreatefromjpeg($url);
imagecopymerge($im, $dest, 10, 10, 0, 0, 180, 180, 100);
```

hope it helps!